# Sembast read only 1 item

Tags: flutter, sembast

How can I read only 1 item from NoSql using Sembast? Every article about reading items are showing me creating a list but I only need just 1 item from databse.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any record using the RecordRef api (and extension): https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast/SembastRecordRefExtension.html

```
// Lint warnings will warn you if you try to use different types
var store = intMapStoreFactory.store();
// add a record, autogenerate a key
var key = await store.add(db, {'offline': true});

// Reading a single record falue
var value = await store.record(key).get(db);
```